# Run bash commands in docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I am using default image and my requirement is to run a few Linux commands when I run docker-compose file. Os is redhat. This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rstudio-package-manager:
    image: 'rstudio/rstudio-package-manager:latest'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '$PWD/rstudio-pm.gcfg:/etc/rstudio-pm/rstudio-pm.gcfg'
    command: bash -c mkdir "/tmp/hello"
    ports:
      - '4242:4242'
```

This is the error:

```
rstudio-package-manager_1  | mkdir: missing operand
rstudio-package-manager_1  | Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

I have to run a few commands after the container starts. It can be added as a bash script too. For that, I tried this

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rstudio-package-manager:
    privileged: true
    image: 'rstudio/rstudio-package-manager:latest'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RSPM_LICENSE=1212323123123123
    volumes:
      - './rstudio-pm.gcfg:/etc/rstudio-pm/rstudio-pm.gcfg'
      - './init.sh:/usr/local/bin/init.sh'

    command:
    - init.sh
    ports:
      - '4242:4242'
```

Inside init.sh is this

```
alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'
rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'
rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran
```

And that also didn't work. Can anyone helpme out?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is your goal, why are you trying to create a directory _inside_ of your new docker container?

Comment: See the EDIT part please :) @knittl

Comment: You need to run it in a separate container, or from outside of Docker entirely.  Anything you put in a Compose `command:` runs _instead of_ the process the container normally runs.

Comment: Can you redirect me to an example? I am new to this environment.

Comment: @Siddharth I have written another answer, that does not modify the `command` in the docker-compose file, but creates a new image.

Comment: Please try to keep a question to just one topic, that's the SO way. Better to start new questions than edit. @knittl has provided an answer to your original question and I think you could mark it as approved.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing 3 arguments to `bash`:

1. `-c`
2. `mkdir`
3. `/tmp/hello`

but you need to pass only two:

1. `-c`
2. `mkdir /tmp/hello`

In other words: `-c` expects a single "word" to follow it. Anything after that is considered a positional parameter.

Therefore:

`bash -c 'mkdir /tmp/hello'`

Comment: Tried this and I am getting this error now  -------     ]# docker-compose up
Recreating rspm_uat_rstudio-package-manager_1 ... done
Attaching to rspm_uat_rstudio-package-manager_1
rspm_uat_rstudio-package-manager_1 exited with code 1

Comment: I don't know what your docker image does or what it provides. Maybe it does not have a `tmp` folder or the user does not have permission. Then the command will fail. If you only run a single command, the container will terminate once the command has executed. it sounds to me like an XY problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, it doesn't sound like you want to change the `command` when running a container, but you want to create a derived image based on an existing one.

You want a `Dockerfile` which modifies an existing image and add your files/applies your modifications.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rstudio-package-manager:
    privileged: true
    build:
      context: folder_with_dockerfile
    image: your_new_image_name
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RSPM_LICENSE=1212323123123123
    volumes:
      - './rstudio-pm.gcfg:/etc/rstudio-pm/rstudio-pm.gcfg'
      - './init.sh:/usr/local/bin/init.sh'
    ports:
      - '4242:4242'
```

`folder_with_dockerfile/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rstudiol/rstudio-package-manager:latest

RUN alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm' && \
  rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages' && \
  rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran
RUN commands in next layer
RUN commands in third layer
```

Then build the new image with `docker-compose build` and start normally. You could also run `docker-compose up --build` to build & run.

Comment: Not working. It says the application should be running for executing these commands in bash. So basically, I need these commands to run after the container is UP. Just something like PostStart function.